# Guardar variable en una base de datos desde javascript

Tags: javascript, json, base-de-datos, discord.js

Muy buenas a tod@s.

Estoy haciendo un bot con discord.js y necesito guardar variables en una base de datos para cada usuario.

El bot hace lo siguiente:

- Manda un pokemon desde un json cada vez que se utiliza el comando.
- Cada vez que se usa dicho comando, la variable "Puntos" aumenta en 3.
- Una vez usado manda el pokemon, se usa otro comando para añadirlo a una base de datos si ese pokemon es la primera vez que es capturado y además la variable "Pokedex" aumenta en 1.

Entonces el problema que tengo es cómo guardar las variables "Puntos" y "Pokédex" de cada usuario en una base de datos.

El código:

```
const lista = require("./ListaPokemon.json");

var Pokedex = 0

var Puntos = 0

//// Pokémon que aparecerán por rutas

const Ruta1 = [lista.WildPokemon.Pidgey, lista.WildPokemon.Rattata]

//// Funciones que hace que salga un pokemon random

function random_item(Ruta1)

{
  return Ruta1[Math.floor(Math.random()*Ruta1.length)];
}

//// Clientes con las instrucciones para el bot

client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content == prefix +"ruta1"){
      var appearedpokemon = random_item(Ruta1);
      
      const filter = m => m.content.includes('s!catch');
      const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter , {time: 20000}); 
    
      var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    
      .setAuthor(`${message.author.username}`,`${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
      .setTitle(`¡Un ${appearedpokemon.Name} salvaje apareció!\n(s!catch para capturar, límite: 20 segundos)\n`)
      .setImage(`${appearedpokemon.Image}`)
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter("Pepe")
    
      Puntos = Puntos + 3
    
      message.channel.send(embed)
    
      collector.on('collect', m => {
        message.channel.send(`¡Has capturado un ${appearedpokemon.Name}!`)
        let pokemon = db.fetch(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`)
        if(pokemon===null||!pokemon.includes(appearedpokemon.Name)) {
        db.push(`pokemonlist_${message.author.id}`, appearedpokemon.Name)
        db.add(`pokemon_${message.author.id}`, 1)
        Pokedex = Pokedex + 1
        message.channel.send(`${appearedpokemon.Name} se ha registrado en tu Pokédex`)
       } 
    
      });
    
      collector.on('end', collected=> {
        message.channel.send(/*`El ${appearedpokemon.Name} salvaje ha huido`*/);
      });
    }})
```

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Le pusiste a tu pregunta la etiqueta discord.py. No querras haber puesto discord.js?

Comment: es lo que puse al principio, pero no me dejaba porque al parecer la única etiqueta de discord es discord.py

Comment: Ya veo. Tengo reputación suficiente para crear etiquetas, así que ahora la pongo yo!

Comment: Se agradece. De todas formas, ¿tienes alguna solución para mi problema?

Comment: No se nada de Javascript, perdona...

Comment: sabes de alguien que sepa?

Comment: Me temo que no... Suerte con encontrar a alguien que pueda solucionar tu problema!

Comment: De todas formas gracias por lo de la etiqueta. Un saludo.

Comment: De nada, saludos! :D